# Specifying compression for native raster Processing algorithms

Tags: raster, pyqgis, qgis-processing, compression

I use QGIS' native `native:fillnodata` Processing tool to fill `NODATA` cells in a raster with a specific value. This works well but the resulting file is huge.

How can I specify raster compression for the written output raster file?

An answer for either the graphical dialog or for the Python parameters dictionary is fine.

Comment: At least the user interface does not offer any way for giving creation options. Can't you use the "GDAL Fill nodata" tool instead?

Comment: I had the same thought but it seems different as I cannot specify a value to use for filling, instead it seems to want to interpolate values from neighboring data cells.

Comment: Gdal_calc https://gdal.org/programs/gdal_calc.html supports creation options.

Comment: Yes but I wouldn't know how to change nodata pixels to data with it.

Comment: What is the current nodata value and the desired value? How many bands?

Comment: -9999 and a single band.

Comment: This doesn't answer your question as asked, but assuming you want to change `-9999` to `0`, you can use a little gdal commandline trick: `gdalbuildvrt -srcnodata -9999 -vrtnodata 0 /vsistdout input.tif | gdal_translate -a_nodata -9999 /vsistdin/ output.tif` will convert all -9999s to 0s (the NoData value will stay as -9999 but all the pixel values that were originall -9999 will change to 0).

Comment: Thanks! But I need to stay in QGIS and with tools that are usable via the Python `processing` API.

Comment: @bugmenot123 the QGIS GDAL Build virtual raster and Translate (convert format) processing tools use the `gdalbuildvrt` and `gdal_translate` commandline tools internally so you can replicate the commandline trick I noted above using QGIS and Python processing and specify a compression.  Still doesn't answer your QGIS native alg compression issue though which I don't think is possible. Suggest you raise an enhancement issue on their bug tracker.

Comment: Does this need to be a one step approach, or are multiple steps acceptable? When you say "huge", what sort of size are you talking about, and what sort of size are you aiming for?

Comment: Single step as the process must not leave any uncompressed files in the temporary directory. "Huge" is meant purely relative, I want compression for reduced memory/storage pressure, regardless of the absolute size.

Comment: When you say "I need to stay in QGIS and with tools that are usable via the Python processing API", does this mean that other Python calls that can be made via the Python Console are not acceptable?

Comment: My question is about the `native:fillnodata` tool but I would reword my question if there is a general solution for all raster-related `native:` tools. I am not looking for a workaround that replicates functionality of the tool(s). I am also not looking for a workaround that re-compresses and removes the output file written by the native algorithm. If the answer is a clear and authoritative, documented "it is (currently) not possible", then that is fine! Monkey-patching something would be fine.